# Apache Spark Null Value when casting incompatible DecimalType vs ClassCastException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, casting

Casting `DecimalType(10,5`) e.g. `99999.99999` to `DecimalType(`5,4) in Apache Spark silently returns `null`

Is it possible to change this behavior and allow Spark to throw an exception(for example some CastException) in this case and fail the job instead of silently return `null` ?

Comment: have you found a clean solution?

Comment: This one caught me off guard and took a long time to track down.

SQL in databases typically fails with loud error on numeric overflow, so I wasn't expecting this behavior at all.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Git hub documentation, https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3ab96d7acf870e53c9016b0b63d0b328eec23bed/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Cast.scala#L499

> /**    * Change the precision / scale in a given decimal to those set
>   in `decimalType` (if any),    * returning null if it overflows or
>   modifying `value` in-place and returning it if successful.    *    *
>   NOTE: this modifies `value` in-place, so don't call it on external
>   data.    */

There is also another thread, suggesting there may not be a direct method to fail the code if not able to cast. [Spark: cast decimal without changing nullable property of column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854815/spark-cast-decimal-without-changing-nullable-property-of-column).
So, probably you can try checking for the `null`value in the casted column and create a logic to fail if any?

Comment: checking for the null value is not a solid solution because it's possible that you have other null values in that column which are not caused by the cast. Unless you replace all null values right before the cast. I would suggest (like it's stated in the thread given above) to write your own UserDefinedFunction which then can throw an exception.

Comment: @RubyVerboven play nice for Java/Scala. For PySpark UDFs are slow, you have to manage an extra pain with Scala UDFs

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above you can try to achieve what you want using a UserDefinedFunction. I'm currently facing the same problem but managed to solve mine using a UDF. The problem I was facing is that I wanted try to cast a column to DoubleType but I don't know the type upfront and I wan't my application to fail when the parsing fails, so not a silent 'null' like you are talking about.

In the code below you can see I've written an `udf` which takes in a `struct` as parameter.I'll try to parse the only value in this struct to a double. If this fails I will throw an exception which causes my job to fail.

```
import spark.implicits._

val cast_to_double = udf((number: Row) => {
  try {
    number.get(0) match {
      case s: String => s.toDouble
      case d: Double => d
      case l: Long => l.toDouble
      case i: Int => i.toDouble
      case _ => throw new NumberFormatException
    }
  } catch {
    case _: NumberFormatException => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't parse this so called number of yours.")
  }
})

try {
  val intDF = List(1).toDF("something")
  val secondIntDF = intDF.withColumn("something_else", cast_to_double(struct(col("something"))))
  secondIntDF.printSchema()
  secondIntDF.show()

  val stringIntDF = List("1").toDF("something")
  val secondStringIntDF = stringIntDF.withColumn("something_else", cast_to_double(struct(col("something"))))
  secondStringIntDF.printSchema()
  secondStringIntDF.show()

  val stringDF = List("string").toDF("something")
  val secondStringDF = stringDF.withColumn("something_else", cast_to_double(struct(col("something"))))
  secondStringDF.printSchema()
  secondStringDF.show()
} catch {
  case se: SparkException => println(se.getCause.getMessage)
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
root
 |-- something: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- something_else: double (nullable = false)

+---------+--------------+
|something|something_else|
+---------+--------------+
|        1|           1.0|
+---------+--------------+

root
 |-- something: string (nullable = true)
 |-- something_else: double (nullable = false)

+---------+--------------+
|something|something_else|
+---------+--------------+
|        1|           1.0|
+---------+--------------+

root
 |-- something: string (nullable = true)
 |-- something_else: double (nullable = false)

Can't parse this so called number of yours.
```